# XCode 4.5.2 working issues

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode4.5

I have recently downloaded Xcode update 4.5.2 and it seems to performing slow. I have tried other applications and everything is running fine. I'm currently developing an app and it's been performing so slowly, that I can't edit an UIlabel box.

Comment: How old is your Mac? Xcode runs like a bloated piece of garbage sometimes on older Macs.

Comment: Is it downloading updates? Check in the upper center panel, just in case.

Comment: Macbook 2010. My problems start within Xcode. This problem has never happened before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case: remove the contents in the  "~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData" - Folder and see if it still stalls. I had a sluggish Xcode once and that helped.

Comment: I can't find a file called "DerivedData". Would it be something else?